# Creating trigger file using pentaho kettle

Tags: pentaho, teradata, kettle, data-integration, pentaho-spoon

I have a log table where it captures log each and every time the main table is loaded, and what i need is that i need to create a trigger file using pentaho kettle each and every time the log table gets updated. And the log table is in teradata.

Any examples or approach to proceed with will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried the `Write to file` or `Create file` step in a job?

Comment: I am working on that now, but i am not sure whether i am doing right

Comment: Try the steps and if they don't work, update your question with the job definition and the results.